# Can I get socket buffer remainder size?

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

I have a real-time system, so I using the non-blocking socket to send my data
But there is happened that the socket buffer is full,
so the send function's return value less than my data length.

If I save the return length and re-send, there is not different with blocking socket?

So can I get the socket buffer's remainder size? I can check it first,
if it is enough then I call send, skip send else.

Thank you, all.

Comment: OS: ubuntu 13.04 64bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a difference between blocking and non-blocking - if you experience a short write you don't block.  That's the whole point of non-blocking.  It give you an opportunity to do something more pressing while waiting for some buffer space to free up.

Your concern seems to be the repeated attempts to write a full message, that is, a form of polling.  But a check of the bytes free in the buffer is the same thing, you are just substituting the call to the availability with the call to write.  You really don't gain anything efficiency wise.

The commonplace solution to this is to use something like `select` or `poll` that monitors the socket descriptor for the ability to write (and least some) bytes.  This allows you stop polling and foist some of the work off on the kernel to monitor the space availability for you.

That said, if you really want to check to see how much space is available there are usually work arounds that tend to somewhat platform specific, mostly `ioctl` calls with various platform specific parameters like `FIONWRITE`, `SIOCOUTQ`, etc.  You would need to investigate exactly what your platform provides.  But, again, it is better to consider if this is really something you need in the first place.

Comment: thank your reply, I already used the select() function. Because my system is a real-time system, so the data will come continually.
I need process them(call send()) as soon as possible.
So If the buffer size have not enough, I can skip this data, that will not destroy my system. But if only send a partial of data and drop the remain data, it will destroy my system.
So I ask this problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  You might want to incorporate some of this information into your question and specify what operating system you are using.

Comment: Hi, seems ubuntu not support FIONWRITE neither SIOCOUTQ, because it is not the C standard library? What can I do for it?

Comment: @neko - Read `man (7) tcp` and search for `SIOCOUTQ`.  It is a parameter to `ioctl`.  You won't find it in the C standard lib because, being platform dependent, it is by definition non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

If the asynchronous `send` fails with `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`, no data is sent. You could then try to send something else, or wait until the buffer is free again.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391208/when-a-non-blocking-send-only-transfers-partial-data-can-we-assume-it-would-r - a related issue is discussed there.