# How does socketcan handle arbitration?

Tags: sockets, can-bus, socketcan

I pretty much understand how the CAN protocol works -- when two nodes attempt to use the network at the same time, the lower id can frame gets priority and the other node detects this and halts.

This seems to get abstracted away when using socketcan - we simply write and read like we would any file descriptor. I may be misunderstanding something but I've gone through most of the docs (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/can.txt) and I don't think it's described unambiguously.

Does write() block until our frame is the lowest id frame, or does socketcan buffer the frame until the network is ready? If so, is the user notified when this occurs or do we use the loopback for this?

Comment: I know long time have passed. Have you ever found an answer to these?

Answer (score 1):

`write` does not block for channel contention. It could block because of the same reasons a TCP socket `write` [would](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5509956/8074683) (very unlikely).

The CAN peripheral will receive a frame to be transmitted from the kernel and perform the Medium Access Control Protocol (MAC protocol) to send it over the wire. SocketCAN knows nothing about this layer of the protocol.

Where the frame is buffered is peripheral/driver dependent: the chain kernel-driver-peripheral behaves as 3 chained FIFOs with their own control flow mechanisms, but usually, it is the driver that buffers (if it is needed) the most since the peripheral has less memory available.

It is possible to subscribe for errors in the CAN stack protocol (signaled by the so called "error frames") by providing certain flags using the SocketCAN interface (see 4.1.2 in your link): this is the way to get error information at application layer.

Of course you can check for a correctly transmitted frame by checking the loopback interface, but it is overkill, the error reporting mechanism described above should be used instead and it is easier to use.